# How to modify just a property from a dexie store without deleting the rest?

Tags: dexie

I'm having the dexie stores showed in the print screen below:

[Dexie stores print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yKJL.png)

My goal is to update a dexie field row from a store without losing the rest of the data.

For example: when I edit and save the field "com_name" from the second row (key={2}) I want to update "com_name" only and not lose the rest of the properties, see first and the third row.

I already tried with collection.modify and table.update but both deleted the rest of the properties when used the code below:

```
dexieDB.table('company').where('dexieKey').equals('{1}')   
//USING table.update
//.update(dexieRecord.dexiekey, {
//    company: {
//        com_name: "TOP SERVE 2"
//    }
//})
.modify(
    {
        company:
        {
            com_name: TOP SERVE 2
        }
    }
)
.then(function (updated) {
    if (updated)
        console.log("Success.");
    else
        console.log("Nothing was updated.");
})
.catch(function (err) { console.log(err); });
```

Any idea how can I accomplish that?

Thanks
Alex

Answer (score 0):

You where right to use Table.update or Collection.modify. They should never delete other properties than the ones specified. Can you paste a jsitor.com or jsfiddle repro of that and someone may help you pinpoint why the code doesn't work as expected.

Comment: See my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

Now that you are saying I realised that company and contact stores are created dynamically and editedRecords store has the indexes explicitly declared therefore when update company or contact store, since dexie doesn't see the indexes will overwrite. I haven't tested it yet but I suspect this is the behaviour.

See the print screen below:

[Dexie stores overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfXiq.png)

Basically I have json raw data from db and in the browser I create the stores and stores data based on it, see code below:

```
function createDexieTables(jsonData) {  //jsonData - array, is the json from db
    const stores = {};
    const editedRecordsTable = 'editedRecords';

    jsonData.forEach((jsonPackage) => {
      for (table in jsonPackage) {
        if (_.find(dexieDB.tables, { 'name': table }) == undefined) {
          stores[table] = 'dexieKey';
        }
      }
    });

    stores[editedRecordsTable] = 'dexieKey, table';
    addDataToDexie(stores, jsonData);
   }

function addDataToDexie(stores, jsonData) {
    dbv1 = dexieDB.version(1);

    if (jsonData.length > 0) {
        dbv1.stores(stores);

        jsonData.forEach((jsonPackage) => {
            for (table in jsonPackage) {
                jsonPackage[table].forEach((tableRow) => {
                    dexieDB.table(table).add(tableRow)
                        .then(function () {
                            console.log(tableRow, ' added to dexie db.');
                        })
                        .catch(function () {
                            console.log(tableRow, ' already exists.');
                        });
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is the json, which I convert to object and save to dexie in the value column and the key si "dexieKey":

```
[
  {
    "company": [
      {
        "dexieKey": "{1}",
        "company": {
          "com_pk": 1,
          "com_name": "CloudFire",
          "com_city": "Round Rock",
          "serverLastEdit": [
            {
              "com_pk": "2021-06-02T11:30:24.774Z"
            },
            {
              "com_name": "2021-06-02T11:30:24.774Z"
            },
            {
              "com_city": "2021-06-02T11:30:24.774Z"
            }
          ],
          "userLastEdit": []
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Any idea why indexes were not populated when generating them dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

Given the JSON data, i understand what's going wrong.

Instead of passing the following to update():

```
{
    company:
    {
        com_name: "TOP SERVE 2"
    }
 }
```

You probably meant to pass this:

```
 {
    "company.com_name": "TOP SERVE 2"
 }
```

Another hint is to do the add within an rw transaction, or even better if you can use bulkAdd() instead to optimize the performance.

Comment: Three docs of modify (which also applies to update) examplifies how to update nested properties. https://dexie.org/docs/Collection/Collection.modify()#sample-using-nested-key